# php mail function not working in if condition

Tags: php

This is my mail function in `php` but it is not working properly.
Please help me sort-out my problem.

```
<?php

if($_POST && array_key_exists('submit_contact',$_POST)){
$to = "info@example.com";
$subject="Contact Form";
$fname =$_POST['fname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$telno=$_POST['telno'];
$mess=$_POST['your-message'];
$body = "<html><body><div>";
$body .= "<h1><b><u>Contact Form Details</u></b></h1>";
$body .= "<h3>Full Name:\t". $fname."</h3>";
$body .= "<h3>E-mail:\t". $email."</h3>";
$body .= "<h3>Telephone:\t". $telno."</h3>";
$body .= "<h3>Message:</h3>\t<p>". $mess."</p>";
 $body .= "</div></body></html>";
$headers = "From:". $email. "\r\n";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To:".$email."\r\n"."Return-Path:". $email . "\r\n". "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
   $subjectr="Confirmation Notice";
  $messages="<html><body>";
      $messages .="<div style=''><a href='index.html'><img src='http://example.com/images/logo.png' alt='logo'/></a></div>";
   $messages .="<table style=''width='600px'><tr><td bgcolor='black'height='30px'><font style='padding-left:10px;color:#d8b53e;font-size:20px;'>Reference # 786733</font></td> </tr>";
    $messages .="<td><br/>Dear Concerned,<br/>Thank you for considering</td></tr>";
  $messages .="<tr><td>&#169; 2014</td></tr></table>";
 $messages .="</body></html>";
  $headerss = "From:".$to. "\r\n";
  $headerss .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headerss .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headerss .= "Reply-To:".$to."\r\n"."Return-Path:".$to. "\r\n". "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
 if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
    mail($email,$subjectr,$messages,$headerss);
      echo "<script> window.alert('E-mail successfully Sent!');</script>";
 }
else{
echo "<script> window.alert('Error Try Again Please');</script>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: plz provide your whole codes

Comment: Is it because you have two s on `$headerss`? Maybe turn error_reporting on, should be easy to troubleshoot.. or an r at the end of `$subjectr`

Comment: no its not headers problem my this code working on some hosting server fine but on some hosting server not fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you put a function in an if-condition it gets invoked automaticlly.
So if you write

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) {
    echo "Send!";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

the EMail will get send and returns true on success otherwise false.

Comment: yes you are right but in if i am send another email of confrmation to sender                                  mail($email,$subjectr,$messages,$headerss); // NOt Working

Comment: Did you ensure that you did everything right? Offical doc: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php

Comment: yes, and remaining all code is error free and working correct

Comment: When you are testing your code on a local server like XAMPP it often happens that mail() returns true without sending a mail but if you upload your script to a "real" server it'll work.